# How to set text align in dataView table in extjs

Tags: html, extjs, html-table, dataview

I have a dataView and i want to set my text like this 
**Details:this is a testttete33 jlkxjcsksjcj jxzlkzxlckjzlcj;c;z zzcjzlcxl ;**
Let me show you mine in the Image[image]

So you see my **Details** field which is not good(align)
and here is my code

```js
items: [{
  xtype: 'dataview',
  itemSelector: 'table',
  itemTpl: [
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '    <table width="100%" class="basic" style="min-height:100px;">',                       
    '        <tr>',
    '            <td width="25%"><b>ID #:</b></td>',
    '            <td width="25%">{id}</td>',
    '            <td width="25%"><b>Name:</b></td>',
    '            <td width="25%">{name}</td>',
    '        </tr>',
    '        <tr>',
    '             <td><b>Details:</b></td>',
    '             <td align="justify">{details}</td>',
    '        </tr>',
    '    </table>',
    '</tpl>'
  ],
  bind: {
    store: '{viewpermission}'
  }
}],
```

Comment: please add a simple fiddle with your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `td align=justify`, and that is what you got. I see in your screenshot that it works.

Your issue is somewhere else. This is how your table looks like right now (exaggeration by me):

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID #    | 29      | Name:   | testme  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Details:| this is |
|         | a  test |
|         | for  me |
|         | 1234567 |
+---------+---------+
```

What you presumably want is

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID #    | 29      | Name:   | testme  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Details:| this  is  a   test  for  me |
|         | 1234567                     |
+---------+-----------------------------+
```

So what you are really searching for is `<td align="justify" colspan="3"`...

Comment: Thanks thats what i need ;)